# looking for duplicated values of a input text inside an array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a little bit new doing this.
I was looking several similar questions around the web, however I'm still having the same doubts
looking through my source code of the web page, I got something like this;

```
<input type="text" name="house[0].adress01" value ="10" >
<input type="text" name="house[0].adress02" value ="11" >
<input type="text" name="house[0].adress03" value ="13" >

<input type="text" name="house[1].adress01" value ="8" >
<input type="text" name="house[1].adress02" value ="41" >
<input type="text" name="house[1].adress03" value ="135" >

<input type="text" name="house[2].adress01" value ="210" >
<input type="text" name="house[2].adress02" value ="41" >
<input type="text" name="house[2].adress03" value ="713" >
```

I just want to compare using Javascript if the value of adress02 is equal  in any of the instances of house.
in the example house[1].adress02 is equal to house[2].adress02
(without using jquery just plain Javascript )

thanks in advance.

---

### this is the code.. as I wrote before, there are a lot of mistakes. ( I know)

```
function checkDirExist(arr) 
{
//var theForm = document; // document.forms.cfgTheHouseForm; //
//var theControl = document.getElementById("house") ;
//var theObject = theControl.getElementById("address02") ;
alert("in checkDirExist wi");
//alert(document.forms[0].house[0].address02);  //No
//alert(document.forms[0].elements["house[0].address02"].value); //Works
//alert(document.forms[0].elements[house[0].address02].value); No
//alert(document.forms[0].elements[house[0]].address02.value); No
//alert(document.form.elements[house[0]].address02.value); no 
//alert(document.forms[0][house[0].address02].value); //No
//alert(document.form.elements[house[0].address02].value);no 
//alert(document.forms[0].elements['house'][0].address02.value); no
//alert(theControl.value);  
alert(document.forms[0].elements["house["+0+"].address02"].value);
//alert(theControl[0].address02); no
// alert(arr[0].address02.value); no


alert("in checkDirExist wiji");
for (var zz=0; zz<arr.length; zz++) 
{
alert(zz);

for(var xx=0; xx<arr.length; xx++)
{
alert(arr[zz].address02.value);
alert(arr[xx].address02.value);
if ( arr[zz].address02.value == arr[xx].address02.value)
{
return true;
break ;
}
else
{
alert("no");
}
}
}
alert("suerte");
return false ;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion you have half of a question here.  You have given a good html snippet and description however it lacks an attempt.  You should add a code sample of what you have tried.  Although it might get shot down by the community as wrong, people feel much better about guiding someone through something and helping them fill in gaps of understanding than they do about providing a complete solution and just doing work for someone else.

Comment: good Afternoon sr kumar, yeap that is the right way to do it, and you are pointing to a issue I found during my research, I don't know anything about how to manage this kind of objects. that is why, before to get you confused with my several attempts, I prefer to ask without code

Comment: Causes giggles not confusion.  We all need humor.  If you hover over the up arrow, the site wants to reward questions that show "research effort", so it's a good idea to do some.  Anyhow, it looks like you have two pretty good samples to work with below, good luck.  Don't forget to make someone happy by accepting and answer and up-voting those you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isDuplicateValue(suffix)
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var values = [];
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
    {
        var name = inputs[i].getAttribute("name");
        if (name.indexOf(suffix,name.length-suffix.length) != -1)
        {
            var value = inputs[i].getAttribute("value");
            if (values.indexOf(value) != -1)
                return true;
            values.push(value);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call isDuplicateValue("adress02") in order to get the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and check for the same value

```
var all  = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="house"]');
var one  = document.getElementsByName('house[0].adress02')[0];
var same = false;

for (var i=all.length; i--;) {
    if ( all[i].name.indexOf('adress02') != -1 && all[i] != one) {
        if (all[i].value == one.value) {
            same = true;
        }
    }
}

console.log(same)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VhYf/2/)